# Transformation integral

Tags: probability, integration

I am studying a proof and have some difficulty understanding the following step:

$\int\limits_0^\infty y dF(t+y) = \int\limits_0^\infty (1-F(t+y))dy$.

Here, F(x) is probability distribution function.
Could somebody explain this equality?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Put $g(y)=1-F(t+y)$, and $h(y)=y$ in
$$\int_{a}^{b} g(y) h'(y) dy = g(y)h(y)|_a^{b} -\int_{a}^{b} h(y) g'(y) dy.$$

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Comment: But how should I compute $(1-F(t+y)y \mid^\infty_0$ ?

Comment: Some CDFs have the property that $\lim_{y\to\infty}y(1-F(t+y))=0$.